# My blander worked normal on my pc today when i went to open it, was asking for opengl 3.3

Tags: error, opengl, network

my blander worked normal on my pc today when i went to open it, was asking for opengl 3.3 try reinstalling but it didn't work, i never needed to put anything for it to open, could this be some kind of virus ??

Comment: You're seeing the message because Blender can't find a suitable GPU on your system that supports OpenGL 3.3. It seems there is an issue with your graphics card driver, GPU or OS. If it worked properly before and you haven't manually updated to a newer version of Blender in the meantime, then this is most likely caused by an automatic update of a graphics driver or OS update.

Comment: Try to find out what GPU you're using, check that it fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender and then install the most recent driver from the manufacturers/vendors website.

Comment: when I put this opengl32.dll the blander is extremely slow, seriously I didn't need anything to open the blander until last month

Comment: Nome do Sistema Operacional Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
Versão 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Compilação 7601
Fabricante do sistema INTEL_
Modelo do sistema DH61WW__
Tipo do sistema x64-based PC
Processador Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz, 3300 Mhz, 2 Núcleo(s), 4 
Versão do SMBIOS 2.6
Pasta do Windows C:\Windows
Pasta do sistema C:\Windows\system32
Dispositivo de inicialização \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Nome de usuário Corei32120-PC\Core i3 2120
Fuso horário Hora oficial do Brasil
Memória Física (RAM) Instalada 8,00 GB

Intel graphics 2000

Comment: Yes it is slow because by placing the DLL in Blender's directory, you using software rendering. This means no hardware acceleration by the GPU. I explained possible causes for Blender not detecting your GPU in my previous comment., Without additional information about your system, e.g.what OS and GPU you're using and the version of the graphics driver, we can only guess.

Comment: Intel HD Graphics 2000 is below the minimum requirements for running Blender with an Intel GPU. You could try to install the most [recent driver from 2015](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24970/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-28-?product=81502) for it, perhaps it will allow you to start Blender. Additional you may want to upgrade your OS, Windows 7 has reached its end of life and therefore doesn't receive security updates anymore.